# I have a minecraft problem wherin as soon as I launch the launcher, it crashes before I can even log in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using Windows 10, technical preview, build 10041 and every time I try launch the actual launch for the game, it crashes with a java crash message displayed (be in mind that I have tried getting the game files from a friend and forcing the game to install packages, but it still won't start at all, so it has nothing to do with the version of the game):

[image: game begins to start]

[image: Game then crashes]

[image: And then it asks to close the program]

Things I have tried:

- reinstalling Java
- Getting the game files from a friend.
- installing the game through other means such as the msi installer.

Comment: Windows 10 is still in Technical Preview mode, I'm thinking this would be happening due to an unresolved compatibility issue between Java and Windows 10. Which version of Java are you running?

Comment: Java is not optimized for windows 10 yet. Downgrade again and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going back to another version of windows, I think it may be Windows 10 doing it, I have had a similar problem with it.

I just went back to windows 7 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 might be interfering with Java. After all, its a technical preview.

If you want to keep Windows 10, then **delete all traces of Minecraft** from your computer. This includes shortcuts, launcher, etc. All of it.

Then reinstall Minecraft using the **.exe** option. I've seen people have a problem with .msi in the past.

Additionally, make sure your **Java is up to date**. You can verify your Java here
-> https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score -1):

I gave the path for java to the launcher, my game crashed like this too but when i specified where the 64bit java was, it worked!